# Redhat stores lock file sin /var/lock/subsys, does ubuntu do similiar?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a ubuntu server, and going to /var/lock I see it is empty.

I do have nginx and mysql running, does each process store their lock files in a custom location?

I'm just learning ubuntu via a book, and it mentioned that if a process is running on redhat, you should see a lock file in /var/lock/subsys.

I'm using ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the pid files, they live under `/var/run`. This will contain small text files that contain the process id of a running process, although if the process dies it might not clean up the pid file. If you want to see if a process is running, you really want to do `ps axf | grep processname`, i.e. for nginx do `ps axf | grep nginx`.